# SASS: Get value of variables after returning a string from list

Tags: sass

Is there a way I can get the value of nth($list , 1)

```
$xs: 600px;
$sm: 960px;
$md: 1280px;
$lg: 1920px;

$list: xs, sm, md, lg;

@mixin respond($media) {
  @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
    @if $media==nth($list, 1) {
      @media only screen and (max-width: nth($list, 1) - 1px) {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this now

```
@media only screen and (max-width: xs-1px) {}
```

I want the value of the variable $xs = 600px;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px - 1px) {}
```

I tried:

```
$nth($scree-size , 1)
$#{nth($scree-size , 1)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no, as what you are looking for are dynamic variable names and they are not well supported. However, I suggest to use a map instead to have a somewhat cleaner code without the need to repeat the variable names and to simplify your mixin in general:

```
$breakpoints: (
  xs: 600px,
  sm: 960px,
  md: 1280px,
  lg: 1920px
);

@mixin respond($media) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $media) {
    @media only screen and (max-width: map-get($breakpoints, $media) - 1px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@include respond("md") {
  .class {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
  .class {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion but how can i look up for the first and last $key of the list?

I want to check @if $media == first(which is xs)  {@content} e@else {@content}

Comment: To get a list of all keys from the map you use the [`map_keys`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_keys-instance_method) function and to get the nth element you use the [`nth` list function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method). So, for example, to get the last key: `nth(map-keys($breakpoints), length(map-keys($breakpoints)))`

Comment: Thanks, I tried a lot of combinations for the nth but your answer resolved my question, I'm using the docs too but I might forgot to close some parentheses.

Anyway your ans helped me so Cheers !